# how to change user password in ubuntu using xargs

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xargs, passwd

I need to change the password of "**vtm**" user to "**abcd12345**" by using **`xargs`** command.

so I wrote this comman

> `printf "vtm abcd12345 abcd12345" | xargs -t -n1 passwd`

but I couldn't change it.

Comment: This looks very odd. xargs splits each argument from the first line and and run passwd with that as an input. that would never work. read the man page of passwd. and maybe https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/567376/how-to-change-your-linux-password-via-a-bash-script can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `chpasswd` command to change password instead.

```bash
# 1. find the user id of `vtm`
> sudo grep "vtm" /etc/passwd.

# 2. change password with `chpasswd`
echo 'userid:abcd12345' | chpasswd
```

Or if you want to change password with `echo`:

```bash
echo -e -n "abcd12345\nabcd12345" | passwd vtm
```